# Access arraylist from BaseFragment in a Recyclerview Adapter without duplicating the code

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist stored in my BaseFragment which I extend to all my fragments so I can access it and avoid code duplication. I need to access this arrayList inside a recyclerview adapter but I dont know how to access it as the class already extends RecyclerView.Adapter so I cant extend to my basefragment to get it. Could someone help me access this?

Comment: Few suggestions: You can pass the ArrayList when you're initializing the adapter, or keep the ArrayList in ViewModel and pass the ViewModel instance to the adapter and then access it. Please elaborate your question more. As in your requirement and what have, you wrote till now.

Comment: Passing it as a parameter when setting the adapter worked. If you would like to put that in as an answer I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: No need to put it as an answer as it was just a suggestion. But glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above by Parag Pawar passing the ArrayList to the adapter from the fragment when Initialising worked perfectly.